# Accelerating an electron to a high speed

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, voltage

Suppose there are two vertical metal plates. They are separated apart by a small distance. While one is grounded, the other one has a potential of some $V$. Now suppose electrons are produced at the grounded plate. Since there is a potential difference the electron will be accelerated to the plate with some final speed:

$$
v=\sqrt{\frac{2qV}{m}}
$$
where $q$ is the charge of an electron and $m$ being the mass of an electron. The voltage and the speed are ~proportional to each other, and it seems there is no limit to how fast it can go.

Now, it is known that of course there is a limit, namely the speed of light. What would happen if I turn the voltage all up to 256kV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the voltage is high enough so that the speed becomes relativistic, two effects precludes becoming superluminal.
First you must now use the relativistic form of newton's second law, with 4-vector velocity and acceleration.
Second you must keep in mind that an accelerating charged particle would radiate with a power proportional to the square of its acceleration (for non relativistic speeds), and proportional to $a^2\gamma^6$ for the relativistic case in which acceleration and velocity are collinear (such as the example you proposed)